# composition of lift's in MT stack

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am having a lot of trouble understanding this compilation error. The code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack                                                                                                                                                              
-- stack script --resolver lts-8.22                                                                                                                                               
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}                                                                                                                                                

import           Network.HTTP.Simple                                                                                                                                              
import qualified Data.ByteString       as BS                                                                                                                                      
import           Control.Monad.Reader                                                                                                                                             
import           Control.Monad.Except                                                                                                                                             
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class                                                                                                                                        
import           Data.Conduit                                                                                                                                                     



type Cmd i o = ReaderT (BS.ByteString) (ExceptT HttpException (ConduitM i o IO))                                                                                                  

runCmd :: Cmd i o a -> BS.ByteString -> ConduitM i o IO (Either HttpException a)                                                                                                  
runCmd cmdTS host = runExceptT $ runReaderT cmdTS host                                                                                                                            


readHost :: Cmd () BS.ByteString ()                                                                                                                                               
readHost = do                                                                                                                                                                     
host <- ask                                                                                                                                                                     
let req = setRequestMethod "GET"                                                                                                                                                
        $ setRequestHost host                                                                                                                                                   
        $ defaultRequest                                                                                                                                                        
lift . lift $ httpSource req getResponseBody
```

Basically I have a MT stack of 4 layers and in `readHost` I am trying to lift an object from the second to bottom layer to the top layer so I have two `lift` composed together. But sadly the code will not compile and I got the following error:

```
[-Wdeferred-type-errors]                                                                                                                                                          
• No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.MonadResource                                                                                                        
                     IO)                                                                                                                                                      
    arising from a use of ‘httpSource’                                                                                                                                        
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely                                                                                                                                     
    ‘httpSource req getResponseBody’                                                                                                                                          
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:                                                                                                                                                  
    lift . lift $ httpSource req getResponseBody                                                                                                                              
  In the expression:                                                                                                                                                          
    do host <- ask                                                                                                                                                            
       let req                                                                                                                                                                
             = setRequestMethod "GET" $ setRequestHost host $ defaultRequest                                                                                                  
       lift . lift $ httpSource req getResponseBody
```

Please help me understand what this error message means.  On a side note, I have not seen people building a stack like this with `ConduiT` sitting at the bottom, so I guess this is bad practice? What will be a good "design pattern" here? I know that the word "design patter" does not exist in haskell but I cannot think of a better word. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just found that changing the last line to `lift . lift $ yieldM $ liftM getResponseBody $ httpBS req` makes the code compilable. This is even more confusing, I think they are equivalent? How come `httpSource req getResponseBody` is not an instance of `MonadResource IO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started by reducing the layers in the monad transformer stack to shrink your
code to this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env stack
    -- stack script --resolver lts-8.22
    {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

    import           Network.HTTP.Simple
    import qualified Data.ByteString           as BS
    import           Control.Monad.Reader
    import           Control.Monad.Except
    import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class
    import           Data.Conduit

    type Cmd i o = ConduitM i o IO

    readHost :: BS.ByteString -> Cmd () BS.ByteString ()
    readHost host = do
      let req = setRequestMethod "GET" . setRequestHost host $ defaultRequest
      httpSource req getResponseBody
```

I then ran `stack {scriptname}` and got an error very similar to the one you got
for the larger stack:

```
    {scriptname}:17:3: error:
        • No instance for (resourcet-1.1.9:Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.MonadResource
                             IO)
            arising from a use of ‘httpSource’
        • In a stmt of a 'do' block: httpSource req getResponseBody
          In the expression:
            do { let req
                       = setRequestMethod "GET" . setRequestHost host $ defaultRequest;
                 httpSource req getResponseBody }
          In an equation for ‘readHost’:
              readHost host
                = do { let req = ...;
                       httpSource req getResponseBody }
```

Figuring out this smaller case may very well make the more complicated version
easier to tackle.

Let's look at the type for `httpSource`:

```
    httpSource :: (MonadResource m, MonadIO n) =>
                     Request
                  -> (Response (ConduitM i ByteString n ()) -> ConduitM i o m r)
                  -> ConduitM i o m r
```

Its return type is `ConduitM i o m r` where `m` must be an instance of 
`MonadResource`.

Now let's have a second glance at the final return type of `readHost`.
It's `Cmd () BS.ByteString ()` which is nothing but
`ConduitM () BS.ByteString IO ()` in disguise.

Compare `Conduit () BS.ByteString IO ()` with `ConduitM i o m r` to see that
`m` corresponds with `IO`.

Is `IO` an instance of `MonadResource`? According to GHC, it isn't.

A little looking around using Hoogle lets us know that `ResourceT IO` is an
instance of `MonadResource`. Let's try it out in a program.

```
    -- stack script --resolver lts-8.22
    {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

    import           Network.HTTP.Simple
    import qualified Data.ByteString           as BS
    import           Control.Monad.Reader
    import           Control.Monad.Except
    import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class
    import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
    import           Data.Conduit

    main :: IO ()
    main = putStrLn "hello"

    type Cmd i o = ConduitM i o (ResourceT IO)

    readHost :: BS.ByteString -> Cmd () BS.ByteString ()
    readHost host = do
      let req = setRequestMethod "GET" . setRequestHost host $ defaultRequest
      httpSource req getResponseBody
```

This compiles without errors and also prints to standard output.

I believe you can use this fix for the larger program. At the very least it explains the error.

Comment: Thanks for working out the error. I've found through reading that the recommended way of doing this is `type Cmd i o = Conduit i o (ExceptT HttpException (ReaderT Text IO))`. There is a library `Data.Conduit.Lift` that is mainly for such constructions.